# AjaxFormValidatingBehavior Performance and Lost focus on Firefox

Tags: ajax, treeview, wicket

My project is using Wicket's *AjaxFormValidatingBehavior* to auto-save form content to Session on sort of a multi-tab form with a tree menu (there is no save button on individual tabs, though there is a "Save" button that actually submits the form, runs the validations and saves contents to database). I am facing few issues:

1. Since the behavior is added to all form components' *onChange* event, there is a server-trip every time user moves from one field to another. I know that a throttle duration can be specified to prevent this, but its not possible to set in my case as my forms are of different lengths/complexity, many components dynamically generated (including the tree menu). But is there a more elegant solution to auto-save form content (that doesn't have a submit button) rather than this annoying solution.
2. Another issue I am facing is that post *onChange* event, on Firefox the component loses its focus after the "server trip" ends. While on IE7 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question I think you need to add a pipelining facility, on your components' `onchange` call a javascript function of your which calls your webapp. You can include a feature similar to the one provided with the throttle duration but page-wide (delay each calls and only trigger the last if it is older than x milliseconds for example).

For the second one, I think you have to use the `AjaxRequestTarget#focusComponent` in your behaviors, or handle this thing in your "wrapper" as described in the first answer.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't lose focus, unless you're refreshing the component the user just focused. I'm really uncertain why this would work in IE7 though